# Filter one buffer and copy it into another C

Tags: c, string, buffer

I'm trying to read a buffer, copy all the non-alphabetical characters and dump it into another buffer.

The problem I'm getting is that whenever I encounter a non numerical character, it won't copy anything more.

I have tried to try to detect the blank spaces, use an auxiliary buffer...

```
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[] = "103 PLUS 1";
    char buffer2[] = "a";
    int i, number;

    memset(buffer2, 0, sizeof (buffer2));
    size_t length = strlen(buffer);

    fprintf(stdout,"Buffer initially: %s \n", buffer);
    fprintf(stdout,"Buffer2 initially: %s \n", buffer2);

    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        if (number = isalpha(buffer[i]) == 0)
        {
            strncpy(&buffer2[i], &buffer[i], 1);
        }
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Copied buffer is: %s \n", buffer2);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `buffer2[]` only has 1 character, a size of 2, and can't hold any more than that. You are indexing it by up to the length of `buffer[]` which is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Run your program in a debugger - that will help you a lot.  Also, I can tell you that your `if (number = isalpha(buffer[i]) == 0)` s/b changed to `if ((number = isalpha(buffer[i])) == 0))`

Comment: @KevinDTimm woops my fault :) I Not defining the size of the buffers was one of the tests I did and forgot to fix it again.

Comment: Please don't change the question. It makes nonsense of the replies. Rolled back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your code leaves the first element of `buffer2` to be 0, indicating the end of the C-string. In fact, the index of same characters should differ in `buffer` and `buffer2`, because characters must be consistent within a C-string, but some characters are not copied.
2. It's unnecessary to initialise `buffer` with `"a"`. Use `{0}` instead.
3. You don't need to use variable `number`.

Refined code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[80] = "103 PLUS 1";
    char buffer2[80] = {0};
    int i, j = 0;

    size_t length = strlen(buffer);

    fprintf(stdout,"Buffer initially: %s \n", buffer);
    fprintf(stdout,"Buffer2 initially: %s \n", buffer2);

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(buffer[i]))
        {
            strncpy(&buffer2[j++], &buffer[i], 1);
        }
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Copied buffer is: %s \n", buffer2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Buffer initially: 103 PLUS 1 
Buffer2 initially:  
Copied buffer is: PLUS
```

Answer (score 2):

When you skip copying a character over, `buffer2` is left w/ whatever was originally in that position, which seems to be 0 (but may not always be), which is why printing it out looks like no other characters were copied.  In fact, they *were*, but the skipped character is interpreted as the null termination of that string.

But worse, you never allocate space for `buffer2`: you let the compiler do it, which means you aren't really allowed to modify that space.  As with the above, you might be getting away with it, but it is undefined behavior, and could actually crash your program.